# How can I find out the validity of a product on Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I don't know what blocks I use to know the expiration date of the product I'm selling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yw3A.png)
I think that's at least it, I just don't know how to find out the validity.And I also have to do this for the supplier, the supplier has to make products that are valid for 3 days

Comment: Hi Pedro, welcome to AnyLogic and SOF. This is question is severely lacking in details, I really struggle to understand what your problem is and what you tried already. What experiration date? What products? What suppliers? We do not know your model, your hierarchy, your data, your setup. Help us help you, check some tips here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow